# Sync PHP Server, iOS and Android Clients

Tags: synchronization, client-server

i want to have an app for android and iOS and a server in PHP.
The clients would use the app offline and would sync with the server. Everything is stored on server and if some new client comes in, it gets all the data from the server.
Additionally the server would be an web app (one more client to sync with the server).

I see there are a lot of existing solutions like parse or firebase.

If i decide to implement it by myself what would you suggest, RestKit?

I think about REST WebService and relational database on the server, because i have relational databases on all clients (SQLite).

What about the sync algorithm?. I read some posts and some are saying to save timestamp and compare it, but what if time on the client is not the same as time on server. Of course i can always sync the time, but what if the client is offline for some time. 
How do you solve this?

Comment: This site is for answering _specific_ programming related questions. Not really for helping you make broad ranging decisions about how to write specific apps.

Comment: Architecture (Sync/Async Client-Server) is defined, languages is defined, so its not that broad. I am not asking how to write something, i am asking how to make a decision and how to solve specific sync problem.

Comment: Well, such a thing is not the purpose of SO: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. I quote from there: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it." Which is Item 4 on the referenced page. By asking "what algorithm to use" it is my opinion you are asking for a "tool" to do the job. In general, SO questions should be more "practical" in nature.

Comment: OK, you got me wrong, its not about the tool, its about what should be taken into account while coding the solution

Comment: OK but that is not a coding issue in itself, that is a design decision and therefore not on-topic if you follow the guidelines:  stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0):

In Android, what about creating a service that checks the server at regular intervals when there is network available (use broadcast reciever and Timer task).
I'm not sure about iOs, but in android, I had implemented this in my app.

Comment: the problem is, if the client is offline, the "creation time" on the client is not the same as "creation time" of entry on the server. Last sync time for client will not be accurate and if between this difference new entry was created on the server, this client won't get entry ever

Comment: I'm sorry, but I didn't understand "creation time" in client. Creation of what? and what about assigning ID to each update? checking IDs are easire than timestamps

Comment: When i insert one new entry in a table, i save the creation time for that entry (insert timestamp). Let's say client time is 6AM and server time is 5AM. Last sync time on the client is 6AM. I create new entry on the server and its insert timestamp is 5AM. The client never gets this one because last sync time on client is 6AM. Is there any better solution than comparing timestamp?

Comment: for each entry, giv an ID, a unique number or string. Another way would be to initially find the difference between the time at server and client, and use that for checking. This could be done by sending the client's time as a request object to the server, find difference, and return the difference.

Comment: and how to decide which ids to sync?

Comment: suppose i have 5 entries synced with client and server havind ids 1-5. Now when i have the client offline update the server with a new entry and id 6. when the client goes online, send a request to the server with the last id it had recieved (here 5). based on that id, sync necessary entries.

Comment: what if the client creates one new entry before connecting to the server. So the client would have 6 entries, the last one with ID 6. The Server has also one entry with ID 6, so we have a conflict

Comment: In that case use naming conventions. entries that client create have ids c1,c2,c3... and server's would be s1,s2,s3... for each sync, check the last updated ids of both categories.